# connecting to oracle database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, oracle12c

It's pretty confusing task to connect to oracle database. There are many steps to follow and I guess I followed almost everything and solved too many errors on the way. Now I'm stuck at this stage with the error

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

my tnsnames.ora file

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
  )
)
```

my ORACLE_HOME path specified in environment variable

```
F:\app\Shuvro\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN;
```

my connectionstring in web.config

```
Data Source=ORCL;User Id=c##shuvro;Password=admin;Persist Security Info=True;
```

tnsping ORCL returned OK.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Oracle 12c Enterprise Database. I installed ODP.NET and ODAC. Now what I'm missing here? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: All seems ok, try to connect via sqlplus. You have only one oracle client installed?

Comment: This could help http://ora-12154.ora-code.com/

Comment: so you trying to connect to Oracle Installed on same machine?

Comment: @bdn02 yah only one oracle client

Comment: @OuSs I went through that too many times before posting question here, no luck. thanks for suggesting anyway

Comment: @SaUce yes I'm trying to oracle installed on same machine

Comment: @MoinulHasan modify tnsnames file to include name of your machine or IP address instead of _localhost_ you can't rely for it to be translated correctly.

Comment: @SaUce omg!! that solved the problem! I just changed the host name from localhost to 127.0.0.1 and all working like butter!! please post your comment and answer so that I can accept it as correct one! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify tnsnames file to include name of your machine or IP address instead of localhost you can't rely for it to be translated correctly.

Comment: thanks a lot man! I just changed the host name from localhost to 127.0.0.1 and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (server instead of data source)

```
Server=ORCL;User Id=c##shuvro;Password=admin;Persist Security Info=True;
```

Comment: this throws ArgumentException with message 'Server' is an invalid connection string attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should download and install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio to connect to oracle database